# Find all linear functionals $X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|\varphi(x)\| \leq \|x\|^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a normed space. Find all linear functionals $X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|\varphi(x)\| \leq \|x\|^2$

---

This was an exam task(easy one, judging by the amount of points possible to obtain from it) I was unable to do.

I tried taking supremum:

$$
|\varphi(x)\| \leq \|x\|^2 \implies \\
\sup_{\|x\|=1}| \varphi(x)| \leq 1^2 \implies \\
\|\varphi\| \leq 1
$$
so all bounded functionals with norm lesser equal to 1 but it was wrong.

How does one solve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Let $a \in X$.

Then for all $y \in \mathbb R \backslash \{ 0\}$ you have
$$
|y|\cdot |\phi(a)|=|\phi(ay)| \leq \| ay \|^2 \leq |y|^2 \|a\|^2
$$

Divide by $|y|$ and set $|y| \to 0$.